run command within container using Ktor-Docker
I have a containerized kotlin backend, and I use ktor docker to generate the dockerfile.
The goal is to install ffmpeg in this same container
How to do it? I don't have access to commands like "runCommand" and "apt-get install" etc.
ktor {
    docker {
        jreVersion.set(JavaVersion.VERSION_17)
        localImageName.set("backend")
        if (apiTagName != null) imageTag.set(apiTagName)
        externalRegistry.set(
            DockerImageRegistry.googleContainerRegistry(
                provider { System.getenv("GCP_PROJECT") ?: "v3" },
                provider { "v2" },
                providers.environmentVariable("GCR_USERNAME"),
                providers.environmentVariable("GCR_PASSWORD"),

                )
        )
    }
}

Thanks
I try this command :
command("apk update && apk add --no-cache ffmpeg")

And here the cloud-run.yml, the backend is in Google Cloud Platform :
deploy-backend:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $XXXX == "XXXX"
      when: always
  image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
  script:
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$XXXX
    - gcloud config set project andragog-$XXX
    - echo -e "XXXXX"
    - gcloud run deploy ${ENV}-backend --region=europe-west1 --image=gcr.io/andragog-$ENV/backend-v2:$XXX
    - gcloud run services update-traffic ${XXX}-backend --to-latest --region=europe-west1
  variables:
    SERVICE: server2
  environment:
    name: $ENV
    action: start

I try to install ffmpeg directly in script.
The installation went well, I found the path where the software was installed: /usr/bin/ffmpeg
But in the GCP cloud shell, nothing in /usr/bin/
